GST Overlay Reference count
After setting Video pipeline's state to PLAYING I am trying to add below
mentioned pipeline dynamically to display an overlay on the
video. overlay buffer will be fed to appsrc once new pipeline is added.
appsrc-->alphacolor-->queue-->capsfilter->overlaysink( sink pad of
olcamerasrc element)
My steps to add pipeline elements:

Add a probe in source pad of olcamerasrc

Inside the call back method of probe
a) Add new elements to pipeline using -gst_bin_add_many
b) Link new elements using - gst_element_link_many
c) Request new sink pad from olcamerasrc.
d) Link overlay sink pad of olcamerasrc and src pad of capsfilter
e) Set state to PLAYING for new  elements

return pad drop


We are seeing a spike in reference count for the overlay elements when state is set to PLAYING using gstreamer function gst_element_set_state?
Before Playing Reference count of appsrc : 1 
Before Playing Reference count of alphacolor : 1 
Before Playing Reference count of alphacolorfilter : 1 
Before Playing Reference count of alphacolorqueue : 1 
Started playing osd pipeline. 1 
After Playing Reference count of appsrc : 6 
After Playing Reference count of alphacolor : 5 
After Playing Reference count of alphacolorfilter : 5 
After Playing Reference count of alphacolorqueue : 7

Can anyone explain reason for this reference count spike when we set the state of pipeline to playing?
We referred gstreamer documentation and didnt find any reference count related info for gst_element_set_state
